# How do you fetch the authors email or IP from /comments? (REST API)

Tags: comments, rest-api, python

Does anyone know how to get the email and IP for Wordpress comments using the REST API? The [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/#retrieve-a-comment). Are the fields just not provided in the response? "author_url" is there. But not "author_email" etc.

```
import requests
import json
import base64

wordpress_user = "xxx"
wordpress_password = "xA5t xcxN xmxK nxyx Fxgx OxKx"
wordpress_credentials = wordpress_user + ":" + wordpress_password
wordpress_token = base64.b64encode(wordpress_credentials.encode())
wordpress_header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + wordpress_token.decode('utf-8')}

api_url = 'https://[site-here].com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?status=all'
response = requests.get(api_url, headers = wordpress_header)
response_json = response.json()
if ( response.status_code == 200 ):
    #
    approved_comments_list = []
    unapproved_comments_list = []   
    for j in response_json:
        if j['status'] == 'approved':
            approved_comments_list.append(j)
        elif j['status'] == 'hold':
            unapproved_comments_list.append(j)

for j in unapproved_comments_list:
    comment_url = 'https://x.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments/' + str(j['id'])
    response = requests.get(comment_url, headers = wordpress_header)
    response_json = response.json()
    print(json.dumps(response_json, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "id": 122,
    "post": 560,
    "parent": 0,
    "author": 0,
    "author_name": "jeff",
    "author_url": "",
    "date": "2022-11-30T20:50:24",
    "date_gmt": "2022-11-30T20:50:24",
    "content": {
        "rendered": "<p>yo dawg. you suck lol</p>\n"
    },
    "link": "https://x.com/hello-world/comment-page-1/#comment-122",
    "status": "hold",
    "type": "comment",
    "meta": [],
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "https://x.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments/122"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "https://x.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments"
            }
        ],
        "up": [
            {
                "embeddable": true,
                "post_type": "post",
                "href": "https://x.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/560"
            }
        ]
    } }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the list of fields in [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/#schema), where `author_email` *is* listed, some fields are only available in the `edit` context. You can set the context by adding `?context=edit` to your request but this will require the request to be [authenticated](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/). This is to ensure that personal data is not publicly exposed.

Comment: I see! Thank you for the solution and clear explanation on the context of things.

https://[site-here].com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?context=edit&status=all